# Is there any optimized way to export CSV of more than 100K record using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 200k locations in my database. So I want to export all the locations into CSV format. While doing this it is taking too much time to download. What is the best way to optimize code in rails?

**In controller:**

```
 def index
    all_locations = Location.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.csv { send_data all_locations.to_csv, filename: "locations-#{Date.today}.csv" }
    end
end
```

**In model**

```
def self.to_csv
    attributes = %w{id city address}

    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << ['Id', 'City', 'Address']

      all.each do |location|
        csv << attributes.map{ |attr| location.send(attr) }
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Is this something that users of your website need to do on a regular base? How often does the data change? Is generating that file on a regular base and caching the result an option? Or is this a one-time task that is done by admins and did you consider database export tools without ruby in between?

Comment: Admin will do it in weekly basis.

Comment: Why don't you generate the CSV file in a cron or background job and mail it to the admins?

Comment: Is there any alternative ways to do it without background jobs?

Comment: Please don't use Indian measurements that are not understood elsewhere, or vague descriptions like "more" -- more than what?

Comment: What database is this?

Comment: That is postgresql database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code with some adjustments with my own data. I made the following changes, and using benchmarking I came to a 7x increase.

Your model:

```
def self.to_csv
  attributes = %w{id city address}

  CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
    csv << ['Id', 'City', 'Address']
    all.pluck(attributes).each { |data| csv << data }
  end
end
```

By using `pluck` you only get the data you want, and then you push all that data into the `csv` array.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using **Postgresql** then you can use this in `application_record.rb`

```
def self.to_csv_copy(attrs="*", header=[])
  rc = connection.raw_connection
  rv = header.empty? ? [] : ["#{header.join(',')}\n"]
  sql = self.all.select(attrs).to_sql
  rc.copy_data("copy (#{sql}) to stdout with csv") do
    # rubocop:disable AssignmentInCondition
    while line = rc.get_copy_data
      rv << line
    end
  end
  rv.join
end
```

and then do

```
Location.to_csv_copy(%w{id city address}, ['Id', 'City', 'Address'])
```

It is even faster than the above solution.